# Python module datetime getting Day -1 (D-1)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I'm trying to write some code that gets a CSV, but the name of that CSV has the date. For example: "myfile-07-09-2021"

I managed to get today's date file, you know how I can read the CSV day -1 (D-1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
from datetime import timedelta
(datetime.today() - timedelta(1)).strftime('myfile-%d-%m-%Y.csv')
```